# Line-Spacing in JTextArea

Tags: java, line, spacing, jtextarea

It seems my current JTextArea instance is having line-spcing about 1 or 1.5. Can anybody tell me how to change the line-spacing in JTextArea instance?

Comment: Hey Surjya, you should upvote and accept answers that you find helpful :-). Did you work out a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 12):

Doing a google search suggests you should be using `JTextPane` and in particular the `setParagraphAttributes` located [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#setParagraphAttributes(javax.swing.text.AttributeSet,%20boolean)).

The way to get the `AttributeSet` you need is as follows:

```
MutableAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setLineSpacing(set, /* your spacing */);
```

Now just pass in `set` to the `setParagraphAttributes` method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer; however, I would recommend grabbing the current AttributeSet from the textpane rather than creating a new one, that way you only need to change the attributes you care about and the others will remain, like so:  

`MutableAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet(textPane.getParagraphAttributes());`

Answer (score 0):

dont forget to put

```
textpane.selectAll();
```

before

```
textpane.setParagraphAttributes....
```

or it will not work!